# Как организовать считывание одного слова?

Tags: ооп, java

Я решил написать простой калькулятор с несколькими функциями.
При вводе слова `help` возникает ошибка. Помогите исправить и напишите почему так,если сможете, так как я новичек.
[Вот код](http://ideone.com/mh3hX)

Comment: Какая ошибка то возникает?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
 at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:53)

Comment: Что значит "двигает итератор"?

Comment: Итератор-это StringTokenizer.Двигает-значит переводит к след. слову 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал код, который выполняет действия очень примитивного калькулятора, надеюсь будет полезным для вас

```
public class SimpleCalc {
    private static List<IAction> actions = new LinkedList<IAction>();

    private static boolean DEBUG_MODE = true;
    static {
        actions.add(createAdd());
        actions.add(createSub());
        actions.add(createHelp());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test usage
        if (DEBUG_MODE) {
            calc(null);
            calc(new String[] { "help" });
            calc(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
            calc(new String[] { "1", "+", "2" });
            calc(new String[] { "5", "-", "4" });
        } else {
            calc(args);
        }
    }

    private static void calc(String[] args) {
        IAction action = findAction(args);

        // handle result
        if (null != action) {
            System.out
                    .println(argsToString(args) + "= " + action.perform(args));
        } else {
            System.out.println("handling error case for args: "
                    + Arrays.toString(args));
        }
    }

    private static String argsToString(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (String arg : args) {
            b.append(arg).append(' ');
        }
        return b.toString();
    }

    private static IAction findAction(String[] args) {
        // no action
        if (null == args) {
            return null;
        }

        // find action
        for (IAction a : actions) {
            if (a.canApplyTo(args)) {
                return a;
            }
        }

        // action not found
        return null;
    }

    private static IAction createHelp() {
        return new IAction() {
            @Override
            public Object perform(String[] args) {
                return "Help system. Only next actions are allowed: add(+), sub(-)";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canApplyTo(String[] args) {
                return 1 == args.length && "help".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]);
            }
        };
    }

    private static IAction createSub() {
        return new IAction() {
            @Override
            public boolean canApplyTo(String[] args) {
                return 3 == args.length && "-".equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]);
            }

            @Override
            public Object perform(String[] args) {
                return Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            }
        };
    }

    private static IAction createAdd() {
        return new IAction() {
            @Override
            public Object perform(String[] args) {
                return Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canApplyTo(String[] args) {
                return 3 == args.length && "+".equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]);
            }
        };
    }

    interface IAction {
        Object perform(String[] args);

        boolean canApplyTo(String[] args);
    }
}
```

Для того чтоб работать с аргументами командной строки: `DEBUG_MODE = false`.

Результат работы в тестовом режиме:

```
handling error case for args: null
help = Help system. Only next actions are allowed: add(+), sub(-)
handling error case for args: [1, 2, 3]
1 + 2 = 3
5 - 4 = 1
```

Comment: Обьясните, пожалуйста принцип действия 
actions.add(createAdd());
actions.add(createSub());
actions.add(createHelp());, 
@Override, perform, т.к. я тоже новичек

Comment: actions содержит список операций которые умеет считать наш калькулятор. поэтому чтоб наш калькулятор умел хоть что-то мы добавляем список 3 действия: обработку операций "help", "+", "-". обьекты создаются соответствующими методами

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка здесь

```
else if(StrTok.equalsIgnoreCase("help")){
```

Объект [StrTokinizer](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrTokenizer.html) не имеет метода `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: У меня ведь класс StringTokenizer

Comment: И что там есть такой метод? Я в доках по линке не нашел (((

Comment: Как же оно вообще скомпилировалось?

Comment: Не как, с ошибкой же

Comment: Скомпилировалось норм.

Comment: Сменил на equals , все равно не работает

Comment: Очень сложно читать твою логику с бесконечными if-else

Comment: Откровенно, не понимаю почему скомпилировалось с equalsIgnoreCase. С equals компилируется, т.к. он наследуется от Object.


Ошибка в обращении к StrTok **после** StrTok.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("bubblegum"), т.к. nextToken "двигает" итератор.

Надо что-то вроде

    if(StrTok.countTokens()==1){
        String s = StrTok.nextToken();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("bubblegum") 
           ...
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("help") 
           ...

Comment: @Роман Берла, теперь работает?

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте `StringTokenizer`:

```
StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.
```

[Class StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Если хотите так, как написали, то тогда уж вот так вот:

Должно быть примерно так:

```
 else if(strTok.countTokens()==1){
        String nextToken = strTok.nextToken();
         if(nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase("bubblegum")){          
             System.out.println("Правильний пароль!");
             }    
         else if(nextToken.equals("help")){
          System.out.println("Вітаємо!Ви завітали до довідки користувача калькулятора!" +
          "Подвійний приклад: 1 + 1 , 432 / 718, 321 - 4569"+
          "Дії над числом (знаки, за їх відсутності на клавіатурі, замінено літерами) " +
          "Наприклад: 12 e , 16 w , 56 y" +
          "Довідка за позначеннями: q-квдрат w-корінь e-синус r-косинус t-тангенс y-катангенс ");
          }
```

Comment: рекомендую вам использовать Enums. Пример сможете найти в книге "Effective java" Joshua Bloch, глава 30 "Use enums instead of int constants". Там как раз есть пример с калькулятором.

Comment: StringTokenizer разбивает строку на части. После чего вам нужно "пройтись" по каждому состовляющему, и проверить, соостветсвует он паролю, команде или хэлпу. 
strTok.equalsIgnoreCase("help"); - это не компилируется

strTok.equals("help"); - а так вы сравниваете строку с объектом другого типа.